# Can I use sensor-fusion for multiple GPS receivers and better my position estimation?

Tags: gps, sensors, sensor-fusion

I am wondering if it makes sense to fuse multiple GPS signals to improve my estimated result. This works fine for example for accelartion sensors, but this sensors have a white gaussian noise.

GPS sensors being mounted on the same board probably suffer from the same errors like drift or multi-path effects, which cannot be corrected by only fuse the sensor readings of this sensors. I imagine that like a constant offset in the same direction, which won t be correct just stays nearly the same.

Furthermore, I have diffrent sensor which I can mount on my drone, even RKT sensor. In my opinion, it makes no sense to fuse a d-GPS with readings from an RKT GPS.

Please correct my if I am wrong.

Thank you in advance and I hope this forum is the right spot to ask that question.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can. Use EKF based approach with onboard multi GPS and multi IMU

[image]

The DJi is doing it, But it is can only prevent one of sensor failure, not the systematic drift patter. To avoid that, you need some more source such as visual odometry or lidar odometry to fuse in the EKF. GPS sate count is good meaure of how bad the position is. It ranges from 0 to 15. So when every one is 15, trust GPS more less variance. When everyone is lower than 6 add very high variance to GPS source.

Yes RTK might be better when you have direct line of sight. But once out of sight, then other GPS might be better. So totaly depends on your use case

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Is there any paper about the DJi? I coudn t find anything so far. The satellite count is a nice idea to verify my sensor readings. The devices I use, already have rtk + multi imu fusion inside. I could only use all my devices and fuse the readings once more. I guess i need to use RTK to get the accuracy I need.

Comment: Emm there won't be any papers about this you can see VINSMONO as they are using DJI N3. But they mention nothing about those detail implementations.   What you can do is to try with Kalman filer or EKF filter based approach to fuse the GPS Data. You can start with this ros package first http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_sensor_fusion/Tutorials/Introductory%20Tutorial%20for%20Multi-Sensor%20Fusion%20Framework . I made it work with this package, its pretty nice